# What is the main differences between "A Streetcar Named Desire" on stage and movie?

Tags: play-adaptation, a-streetcar-named-desire

What are the main differences between the two versions (stage and movie) of **A Streetcar Named Desire**?

I know Elia Kazan, dealing with censorship, had to change a considerable amount of the screenplay and it's more noticeable in the end of the movie. But I'm pretty sure the changes aren't limited to that. Does anybody know the full plot differences between two versions?

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference is that Blanche Dubois lost her young lover because he was a homosexual, and not because he "couldn't hold a job".

Comment: IIRC the endings are quite different as well